Not getting past the If statement
I am coding and got this script from AlvinBlox but it isnt getting past the if statement this is my script right now Where it says print("Got past if statement") is where the promblem is and the problem is the if not remoteData:FindFirstChild(player.Name) then return "NoFolder" end
Remotes
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteData = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteData")
local cooldown = 1

replicatedStorage.Remotes.Lift.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    
    print("FIRED")
    
    if not remoteData:FindFirstChild(player.Name) then return "NoFolder" end
    
    print("Got past IF statement")
    
    local debounce = remoteData[player.Name].Debounce
    
    if not debounce.Value then
        
        debounce.Value = true
        
        player.leaderstats.Strength.Value = player.leaderstats.Strength.Value + 1 * (player.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value + 1)
        
        wait(cooldown)
        
        debounce.Value = false
        
    end
    
end)

stats
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local Strength = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    Strength.Name = "Strength"
    Strength.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local Rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    Rebirths.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local dataFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
    dataFolder.Name = "dataFolder"
    dataFolder.Parent = serverStorage.RemoteData
    
    local debounce = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    debounce.Name = "Debounce"
    debounce.Parent = dataFolder

module
local module = {}
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

function module.Lift()
    
    replicatedStorage.Remotes.Lift:FireServer()
        
end
    
return module

local script
local module = require(script.Parent:WaitForChild("ModuleScript"))
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    module.Lift()
end)`

expecting it to get past the if statement and tried changing a couple of things

Have you printed the condition of the if statement? have you printed all the children of the remoteData? It seems that player.name is not in that list of children so why do you think it should be?

Thanks so much i will try that and inform you if it worked

It worked i must have been just too eager to get it done Tysm
